# Incremental sum a list of numbers in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
my_list = [0, 219, 211, 212, 212]
```

I need to sum the items in this way:

item+item, (item+item)+item, (item+item+item)+Item...

0+219, (219)+211, (430)+212, (641)+212

To be clearer, this is the sum I need to get:

```
new_list = [219, 430, 641, 853]
```

I think the solution might be a list comprehension, and something like this would return just the sum of each item with the next though.

```
[(x + y) for (x, y) in zip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:])]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where did `853` suddenly come from? Shouldn't it be `[219, 430, 642]`?

Comment: 641?? Explain the math.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: they added `211` twice.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the last item. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... or something like this maybe:

```
b = 0
b = [sum(a[:k]) for k in range(1+len(a))]
```

It is likely not overly efficient for large lists.

This test:

```
a = [7, 11, 24, 38]

b=0
b = [sum(a[:k]) for k in range(1+len(a))]

print(a)
print(b)
```

gave:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>>
[7, 11, 24, 38]
[0, 7, 18, 42, 80]
>>>
```

Or do what Martijn suggested and use itertools.

(As an aside - will the Python culture of 'go find a library to import' kill the art of coding?)

Comment: My answer doesn't use `itertools`, because this is Python 2 and not Python 3. My answer merely credits the Python 3 `itertools` *documentation* as the source for the function I proposed the OP use.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!                                                          b = [sum(a[:k]) for k in range(1+len(a))]

Answer (score 8):

You could copy the [`itertools.accumulate()` documentation description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) from Python 3:

```
import operator

def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    'Return running totals'
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5], operator.mul) --> 1 2 6 24 120
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        total = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

This will sum the values from the input list, producing a running total:

```
>>> my_list = [0, 219, 211, 212, 212]
>>> list(accumulate(my_list))
[0, 219, 430, 642, 854]
```

You could tailor the pattern to your specific case, remove the `func` customisation point and ignore the first total:

```
def accumulate(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        total = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    for element in it:
        total += element
        yield total
```

Now it produces 3 values for 4 inputs:

```
>>> list(accumulate(my_list))
[219, 430, 642, 854]
```